# Stop animation on child div when hover over parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and a child div. The css animation is set on parent div. But the problem is on hover over parent div the child div is also taking that effect which I don't want.

Here is my code

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div style="background: url('http://www.screensavergift.com/wp-content/uploads/GoldenNature2-610x320.jpg') no-repeat; background-position: 25% 50%; background-size: cover;" class="menu_item">
        <div class="menu-box-border"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/4eewp8x0/

I don't want the gold border box to be expanded.

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you scale an element you are also going to scale its children.  I don't believe there is a way around that.

In this case you can make the two elements siblings instead and add the `:hover` to the wrapping element:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div style="background: url('http://www.screensavergift.com/wp-content/uploads/GoldenNature2-610x320.jpg') no-repeat; background-position: 25% 50%; background-size: cover;" class="menu_item">        
    </div>
    <div class="menu-box-border"></div>
</div>
```

```
.wrap:hover .menu_item {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eewp8x0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could counter the scale of the parent with a reciprocal value:

```
.menu_item:hover * {
    -moz-transform: scale(.909);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.909);
    transform: scale(.909);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4eewp8x0/2/)**

This has an undesirable movement, though. It may be better to position the child element absolutely, taking it out of the influence of the parent.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately `1/1.1` is a repeating decimal so it's slightly off.  Though I'm unsure if it's really that tiny difference or just rounding precision loss in the animation that causes the slight movement.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and that little trick. In FF the inner box is moving a little bit.

Comment: Yup. As I said. My alternative solution is exactly what James provided.